# React generic type prop must extend other type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm kinda new to typescript so this one is confusing for me. I wanted to pass generic type into my hoc. I need to pass component props as a generic type to get Component with that types on it.

```
const withHOC = <T extends {}>(Component: ComponentType<T>) => (props: T) => {
   return (
       <Component {...props} />
   )
}
//example: const MyView = withHoc<ViewProps>(View)
```

What I don't understand is that I can't just set `<T>` as generic type, I must set it as `<T extends something>`. With that said if I don't pass generic type (as shown in example) I wont get typescript warning for not passing generic type.Can someone explain me why is that happening?

I want it to look like this:

```
const withHOC = <T>(Component: ComponentType<T>) => (props: T) => {
   return (
       <Component {...props} />
   )
}
```

So when I don't pass generic type when calling withHOC, it warns me there has to be one. I might me doing everything wrong and asking for something that is not achievable so correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate questions here:

#### 1. `<T>` vs. `<T extends something>`

> I can't just set `<T>` as generic type, I must set it as `<T extends something>`.

This is a syntactical issue when using arrow functions in `.tsx` files, as the `<T>` can be confused for a JSX expression.  It is possible to use just `<T>` instead of `<T extends something>` if you convert from an arrow function to a traditional `function` declaration.

```
function withHOC<T>(Component: ComponentType<T>) {
    return function (props: T) {
        return (
            <Component {...props} />
        )
    }
}
```

#### 2. Requiring `<T>`

> If I don't pass generic type (as shown in example) I wont get typescript warning for not passing generic type. Can someone explain me why is that happening?

> I want it to look like this ... So when I don't pass generic type when calling withHOC, it warns me there has to be one. I might me doing everything wrong and asking for something that is not achievable so correct me if I'm wrong.

TypeScript will infer the type for `T` each time that you call `withHOC` based on the type of the `Component` argument that you call it with.

Let's say that you have the following code:

```
const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => (
    <button {...props}/>
);

const WrappedButton = withHOC(Button);
```

The `Button` argument matches the type `ComponentType<ButtonProps>`, so TypeScript determines that the `T` for this `withHOC` call is `ButtonProps`.
[image: IDE screenshot]

This is called [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) and it is a powerful feature of TypeScript.

You don't need to explicitly set `<T>` using `withHOC<ButtonProps>(Button)` because it is already known.

There probably exists some tricky way to require an explicit `<T>` but it's not trivial and I don't see why you would want this.

Comment: That perfectly explains it, by passing generic type I could determine which props do I use for which component (e.g. If it's Button it gets onPress + custom props, if it's text I don't need onPress - simplified). Thats why I tried to use it